# RequiredFieldValidator not working

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

With the following simple mark-up, I get very strange behaviour in FF and IE8.  If I give the textbox focus, and tab out, nothing happens.  If I give a user name value, and erase it immediately, nothing happens.  However, only when I supply a user name, tab away, the erase it and tab away again, do I finally get a red star "required" mark.  The summary doesn't show at all.

This is the markup I was trying with.  Looks like my issue was with EnableClientScript and ValidationGroup:

```
<asp:Label ID="userNameLabel" runat="server"
           AssociatedControlID="userNameText">
           User Name:
</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="userNameText" runat="server" 
             Width="200px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="userNameRequired" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="userNameText" 
                            Display="Dynamic" 
                            EnableClientScript="true" 
                            ValidationGroup="userValidation"
                            ErrorMessage="User Name is always required.">
           *   
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `EnableClientScript="true"` is even needed? I think it defaults to that.